# Launchimage support in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, iphone

My app is only for iPhone Landscape. I have added default image with 480*320 size.

But, that image is not supported for me.

How do I set the Launch image only for Landscape orientation?

Comment: As per my knowledge, launch image in iPhone supports only portrait orientation. However, you can rotate your landscape image right/left(so that it now becomes 320*420 and looks rotated).. and use it as portrait launch image. When the launch image comes up, it will look like it got launched in landscape..

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use 480x320 size image. You have to use 320x480 image like below:

[image]

And image name will be `"Default.png"`

Try this one :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to targets -> general -> Launch Images. You will find like above. Click the folder icon to change image.